# UIContoller interaction problem in navigation based iPhone Application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have created a windows based application in Xcode. I pushed the UIViewContoller in the stack of navigation as a subview. But the problem is that I can not interact with the controls on the subview. I am new on iPhone development. So I don't know how to get things done. Please help me in this regard. Bundles of thanks in advance :)

Here is the way I am pushing subview in navigation view controller

```
if(self.userViewController == nil)
{
    UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc]    initWithNibName:@"UserViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.userViewController =vc;
    [vc release];
}

userViewController.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Edit User"];
ShoppingListAppDelegate *delegate = [[ UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[delegate.navController pushViewController:userViewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, read the [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) provided in the Apple Documentation for iOS. Careful reading and following the examples will provide a solid foundation to learning iOS and view controller basics.

That being said, the correct way to push a view controller onto the navigation controller stack is:

**in the .h file**

```
@interface YourViewController : UiViewController {
    UINavigationController *navigationController;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

**in the .m file**

`@synthesize navigationController;`

**in your function where you want to push the new view**

```
UserViewController *myView = [[UserViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UserViewController" bundle:nil];
[navigationController pushViewController:myView animated:YES];
[myView release];
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong in his code as far as pushing viewcontroller on navigation controller is concerned...Rather your code is faulty as no need to take UINavigationController in YourViewController as application delegate is already have one...

Answer (score -1):

try to set `userInteractionEnabled` property true of all controls as well as userViewController...